# What is the appropriate distance metric when clustering paragraph/doc2vec vectors?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, distance, doc2vec, hdbscan

My intent is to cluster document vectors from doc2vec using HDBSCAN. I want to find tiny clusters where there are semantical and textual duplicates.

To do this I am using gensim to generate document vectors. The elements of the resulting docvecs are all in the range [-1,1].

To compare two documents I want to compare the angular similarity. I do this by calculating the cosine similarity of the vectors, which works fine.

But, to cluster the documents HDBSCAN requires a distance matrix, and not a similarity matrix. The native conversion from cosine similarity to cosine distance in `sklearn` is `1-similarity`. However, it is my understanding that using this formula can break the triangle inequality preventing it from being a true distance metric. When searching and looking at other people's code for similar tasks, it seems that most people seem to be using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(data, metric='cosine')` which is defines cosine distance as `1-similarity` anyway. It looks like it provides appropriate results.

I am wondering if this is correct, or if I should use angular distance instead, calculated as `np.arccos(cosine similarity)/pi`. I have also seen people use Euclidean distance on l2-normalized document vectors; this seems to be equivalent to cosine similarity.

Please let me know what is the most appropriate method for calculating distance between document vectors for clustering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in practice cosine-distance is used, despite the fact that there are corner-cases where it's not a proper metric.

You mention that "elements of the resulting docvecs are all in the range [-1,1]". That isn't usually guaranteed to be the case – though it would be if you've already unit-normalized all the raw doc-vectors.

If you have done that unit-normalization, or want to, then after such normalization euclidean-distance will always give the same ranked-order of nearest-neighbors as cosine-distance. The absolute values, and relative proportions between them, will vary a little – but all "X is closer to Y than Z" tests will be identical to those based on cosine-distance. So clustering quality should be nearly identical to using cosine-distance directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use cosine-distance then. I implemented the angular distance function in sklearn but it gave me less clusters.

Answer (score 2):

The proper similarity metric is the dot product, not cosine.

Word2vec etc. are trained using the dot product, not normalized by the vector length. And you should *exactly* use what was trained.

People use the cosine all the time because it worked well for bag of words. The choice is not based on a proper theoretical analysis for all I know.

HDBSCAN does not require a metric. The 1-sim transformation assumes that x is bounded by 1, so that won't reliably work.

I suggest to try the following approaches:

- use negative distances. That may simply work. I.e., d(x,y)=-(x dot y)
- use max-sim transformation. Once you have the dot product matrix it is easy to get the maximum value.
- implement HDBSCAN* with a similarity rather than a metric

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you sure about the dot product? In the original doc2vec paper the authors use cosine too. I guess testing and seeing what happens with what you said does not hurt. I think reimplementing HDBSCAN is a little outside of my scope though :)